# iOS icon resolution/management "within" application

Tags: ios, icons, resolution

i am completely new to this, but i was not able to find anything about it.
In order to make my applications main icon use the native resolution of a specific iOS device, a lot of different image resolutions are required and need to be loaded. This is also applicable for LaunchImages.

What I am missing is: 
What about the icons used within the application?
How do i handle the resolution of this icons and how are they set properly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure. Let's say you open up the default "Music" application on an iPhone by pressing the APPLICATION icon within the Home window. WITHIN the application are also icons used, like the Playlists, Artists, Songs Icons.... So how do i manage to get the right size for these icons with multiple iOS Devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are exporting images you created, export 3 different sizes, one is for non-retina screens like iPhone 3GS (it's unnecessary nowadays), one with 2x the width and height with a surfix of "@2x", another with 3x the width and height with a surfix of "@3x".

Then you put these three images in Xcode `image.xcassets` file, so when you access these images, iOS will automatically match the right image with the right device.

I'm both a programmer and a designer, Xcode makes doing this a breeze. Have fun!